# Where does 1/Gamma characteristic angle come from in EM Radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Very curious as to where this angle comes from? It describes the peak of radiation for almost all radiation regimes, but I am having a difficult time seeing where it comes from.

Also, the physical significance of it.

Thanks in advance!